# G++ Compilation Statistics

Tags: c++, gcc, statistics, code-metrics

I was wondering if there is any way to gather statistics from GCC/G++ compilation process. Metrics like the number of lines compiled in the entire process, total time spent compiling, number of errors/warnings, number/size of compiled objects and so on.

I would like to make a script ( maybe in python ) to generate statistical information in a daily, weekly and monthly basis.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: You could probably add shell scripts to your makefile to get the information you need.

Comment: How about the parameters listed in http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-3.4.4/gcc/Debugging-Options.html ?

Comment: gcc/g++ has verbosity-settings to the holy-heavens. If it is anywhere it will be in their command-line documentation. I'd be shocked if it wasn't available.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I know one, it's called [Cdash](http://www.cdash.org/) and it's part of a larger and ideal suite that virtually includes Cmake, Ctest and Cpack.

[This](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8Ut9o4OdSC0) will probably be an interesting video for you

Comment: +1 This looks pretty interesting. I'm already working with CMake successfully, but have my own reporting strategies on top.

Comment: I'll watch this video latter but it seems quite interesting because I use cmake in my projects...